# The canvas.drawpath not work for me

Tags: android, canvas

```
    int size = 500;
    int xInterval = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        float x = xInterval * i;
        float y = (float) (Math.random() * 300);

        if (i == 0) {
            mLinePath.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            mLinePath.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        canvas.drawText(i + "", x, y, mTextPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawPath(mLinePath, mLinePaint);
```

I put the codes above in the `onDraw` method but the path was not shown, the text was shown, I have doubt that whether the point size were too large? How can I solve this problem?
And the code of the paints initialized:

```
    mLinePaint = new Paint();
    mLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mLinePaint.setDither(true);
    mLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mLinePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setDither(true);
    mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: How do you initialize `mLinePaint`? Actually, I mean, what attributes are you setting on that Paint object?

Comment: mLinePaint = new Paint();
        mLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLinePaint.setDither(true);
        mLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mLinePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Are you getting a warning in your logcat from `OpenGLRenderer` that says `Path too large to be rendered into a texture`?

Comment: Yes, I got it. It said that there is size limition of the path? If I really want so much points, how can I draw the path on the canvas?